# how to extract some part of string from a table in oracle using REGEXP_SUBSTR() (condition excluding preceding part of first space)

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-substr

lets say we have table as

```
with table1 
as
(
select 'CS issue-result info' col1
from dual
union all
select 'ITP decile info' col1
from dual
union all
select 'DFSD fdb-quentile-info' col1
from dual
union all
select 'EUR transcription info' col1
from dual
union all
select 'ABPK stability control info' col1
from dual
)
select *
from table1;
```

i.e. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsnQa.png)

my expected output is as below

```
col1
issue-result info
decile info
fdb-quentile-info
transcription info
stability control info
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5HJR.png)

condition : from the string preceding part of first space should be removed

Comment: What is the desired result if there is no space at all in the input string? (Alternatively, if that is never possible, you need to say that explicitly when you state the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to remove the first "element" of the string.  For this, you can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select t.*, regexp_replace(col1, '^[^ ]+ ', '')
from table1 t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with a capture group:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(col1, ' (.*)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS col1
FROM table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for test case!

I wouldn't do that with regular expressions; for large data set, that's probably slower than a simple `substr + instr` combination:

```
 <CTE here>
 19  select substr(col1, instr(col1, ' ') + 1) result
 20  from table1;

RESULT
---------------------------
issue-result info
decile info
fdb-quentile-info
transcription info
stability control info

SQL>
```

Comment: This runs into problems should the `col1` value happen to be just a single word (my answer also fails in this regard).

Comment: Right, @Tim, but - that's not what the OP's test case suggests, and there's no evidence that such data exist. If so, we'll have to modify our queries.